# Why is event data stored in every Sitecore database?

Tags: events, event-queue

A table named `EventQueue` is present in every Sitecore database. It seems to contain local and remote events of Sitecore instances.

Why are some of these events stored in the Core, some in the Master, and some in the Web database? What is the reason behind this separation?

Comment: + 1 very focused question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe the primary reason is each event has an associated target database.

Found a brief explanation [here](https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/basics-of-sitecore-event-queue/) by Kiran Patils on how the event queuing works:

1. The CM instance triggers an event such as "publish:end:remote".
2. The triggered event is added to the **EventQueue** table in the database that is targeted by the event. For example, the *publish:end:remote* event will be queued up in the publishing target database, typically the **web** database (unless you’ve specified custom publishing targets/databases).
3. Every 2 seconds, your CD instances poll the **EventQueue** table in the database from which they are retrieving content.
4. If they find an event queued up in the **EventQueue** table, they attempt to handle the event according to the handlers defined in the */sitecore/events* section in their respective **web.config** files. For instance, by default the *publish:end:remote* event is configured to execute the **HtmlCacheClearer** handler for the *website* site. Handlers can be added or removed as needed.

**Note:** the interval at which your CD instances poll the **EventQueue** table is configurable in the *web.config* file under the */sitecore/eventQueue/processingInterval* node.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that most often Web DB events target CD servers, Master DB events target CM servers, and Core DB events target all servers (but are rarely used due to the scarcity of Core DB changes)?

Comment: I see it as remote events target CD servers and local events target CM servers. There are a number of events fired locally and remotely and each have a purpose for their respective database. When a publish occurs from Master to Web, you should expect the event tables to populate and inform agents that indexing should run based on what's in the queue.

Comment: +1 Good use of blog post *and* calling out the relevant details.

Answer (score 8):

### Answer

All databases have an `[EventQueue]` in order to help spread out responsibilities and reduce the load on a particular database.

### Explanation

The `[EventQueue]` table exists as a means of communication among all web servers that connect to it. One web server can queue an event in any database it has access to. This event is then read by any other web server in a cluster that also has access to the same database. Most typically, this is the System Event Queue. Which is defined in the config as:

```
/sitecore/eventing/providers/sitecore[systemDatabaseName]
```

The System Event Queue is special for a few reasons:

- Sitecore makes the assumption that all web servers in a cluster can connect to this database
- Sitecore assumes all web servers in a cluster have the same database set as the `systemDatabase`
- Queuing a `RemoteEvent` via `EventManager` uses the `systemDatabase`

  - `Sitecore.Eventing.EventManager.QueueEvent(TEvent event);`

While the System Event Queue is just a bit *special*, it still gets processed the same as the other databases. Also, please note, the System Event Queue, i.e. the **Core** database will often hold significantly more records than the other databases.

All web servers poll the `[EventQueue]` table of **all** "Sitecore Databases" (`Factory.GetDatabases()`) they connect to for new `RemoteEvents`, not *just* the System Event Queue. Therefore, the following statement is true in many scenarios:

> A CD server polls both **Core** and **Web**, whereas a CM server 
>   polls **Core**, **Master** *and* **Web**. Specifically, it executes the
>   following pseudo-query each time:

***Find all new events where (the InstanceName is equal to my InstanceName and the event is set to RaiseLocally OR the InstanceName is not equal to my InstanceName and the event is set to RaiseGlobally)***

[I have a thorough post including an animation](https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2018/02/sitecore-event-queue-visual-diagram/) of an example `[EventQueue]`. Per this post- know that the animation will occur simultaneously for all databases that a web server has a connection to.

### Common Misconceptions

#### Remote Events vs *Local* Events

The `[EventQueue]` only operates with `RemoteEvents`. It does not require knowledge of *local* events such as `publish:end:remote`. While the `publish:end:remote` handlers do execute, the process for getting there makes a few hops.

Take the following example: A content author executes a publish from a CM server. The publish process completes and the **web** database has a new `RemoteEvent` queued up:

`Sitecore.Eventing.Remote.PublishEndRemoteEvent`

And the raw data passed is (as an example):

```
{
"CompareRevisions":false,
"Deep":true,
"FromDate":"\/Date(1515701069888)\/",
"LanguageName":"en-GB",
"Mode":3,
"PublishDate":"\/Date(1520448918977)\/",
"PublishingTargets":["{8E080626-DDC3-4EF4-A1D1-F0BE4A200254}"],
"RepublishAll":false,
"RootItemId":"651c7676-dcbd-49f6-a1b7-b9d31e4c6747",
"SourceDatabaseName":"master",
"TargetDatabaseName":"web"
}
```

Notice that this is a fully qualified type with data. The `[EventQueue]` intrinsically has no idea what `publish:end:remote` is- it only operates on a set of defined types that are mapped to methods.

During app start (`<initialize>`)- the `Sitecore.Eventing.Remote.PublishEndRemoteEvent` type is mapped to a method- this method:

```
Sitecore.Eventing.Remote.RemoteEventMap -> SetupRemoteEventSubscribers()
```

Sets up:

```
    private static void OnPublishEndRemoteEvent(PublishEndRemoteEvent @event)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) @event, nameof (@event));
      Event.RaiseEvent("publish:end:remote", (IPassNativeEventArgs) new PublishEndRemoteEventArgs(@event));
    }
```

Notice that this is what raises the *local event* `publish:end:remote` and processes the data that is included with the queued event. `publish:end:remote` by itself is simply a naming convention and does not imply that an event has to be executed on a remote server.

> Side Note: You could also *Subscribe* to the
>   `Sitecore.Eventing.Remote.PublishEndRemoteEvent`, which would provide
>   you with the raw publish data, instead of the filtered version that is
>   passed to the `publish:end:remote` local event. Which fundamentally does the same thing as adding a handler to the `publish:end:remote` section.

For an excellent explanation of a local event vs a `RemoteEvent`, view this thorough write-up on the [Sitecore Community GitHub](https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/pipelines-and-events/events/).

The `[EventQueue]` as a unit, thinks like this:

> Once a record is added to the `[EventQueue]` with a type of
>   `Sitecore.Eventing.Remote.PublishEndRemoteEvent`, execute the method
>   `OnPublishEndRemoteEvent` and pass to this method the data included in
>   the `[EventQueue]` record.